# sort on the price range in oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following price ranges for the rows, `$0-$50, $50-$100, $100-$500, $500+` defined as varchar2 column. I would like to sort on the rows with the values in the above given order. can anyone suggest me an idea to do that.

Comment: Can you provide what have you tried yet?

Comment: I did not understand where to start from and how to..

Comment: Please provide table structure, sample data and desired results.  Guessing you want to `order by` with a  `case` statement.

Answer (score 2):

You can do what you want using `regexp_substr()`.  However, a `case` is probably easiest:

```
order by (case pricerange
            when '$0-$50' then 1
            when '$50-$100' then 2
            when '$100-$500' then 3
            when '$500+' then 4
            else 999
          end)
```

Comment: how to do a desc order if i use the case ?

Comment: Just add `desc` after the expression:  `end) desc`.

Comment: can i use `decode` and `regexp_substr()` in order by like this? `order by  decode(sign(regexp_substr ('1 asc nulls last', '^(\d)*') - 7), '-1', '1 asc nulls last', (case pricerange
            when '$0-$50' then 1
            when '$50-$100' then 2
            when '$100-$500' then 3
            when '$500+' then 4
            else 999
          end))` because its not working for me, the sort is failing on this query

Comment: You probably can use `decode` and `regexp_substr()`.  I find that solution more complicated.  And, I have a strong preference for `case` over `decode`.

Comment: can you give me an example query ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe do you take into consideration something like this.
`WIDTH_BUCKET(exp, min,max,buckets_cnt)`. The function assigns exp to its bucket. And it creates buckets_cnt + 2 
The following example creates 5 buckets `WIDTH_BUCKET(price,50,500,3)`.

```
(500-50)/3 = 150 
0 - <50 less than min 
1 - (50 : 200)
2 - (200 : 350)
3 - (350 : 500)
4 - 500> more than max



with prod_table as( select 'A' prod_name, 49 price from dual 
                     union all 
                    select 'B' prod_name, 100 price from dual 
                     union all 
                   select 'c' prod_name, 200 price from dual 
                         union all 
                   select 'd' prod_name, 300 price from dual 
                       union all 
                   select 'e' prod_name, 1000 price from dual) 
SELECT prod_name, price,WIDTH_BUCKET(price,50,500,3) from prod_table  order by WIDTH_BUCKET(price,50,500,3)  desc
```